# How do I set up an internal link in react that navigates the current document

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to put together my portfolio and decided to make it using react. One issue I am finding is I originally had my homepage for my portfolio set up as a single html file, with a nav that would internally link to different parts of the document. I want the homepage to be one document and display everything, but still be able to link internally on that document to jump between locations within the page. Is there a way to handle this using react Link? I was setting an id in different sections of my html to handle the internal links in my original html file

Answer (score 1):

I don't think react-router can do this natively. I can recommend two libraries; react-router-hash-link and react-scroll.

Alternatively, you could implement this using native Javascript (wrap this logic in a separate React component) like this:

```
document.getElementById("sectionID").scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```